# Unable to change the dragged item on drop

Tags: html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I am new to jQuery. I have a requirement of drag and drop where i got '3 draggable div' with id 'parent1, parent2 and parent3' to be dropped in a "container div drop-parent".

Scenario:
When i drag the div with id 'parent1' on container div 'drop-parent' it get dropped but when i choose 'parent 2' div to drop it isn't able to replace the div 'parent1' and to come at its inital position. Please refer below JSBin link for same [click here]

```js
$(".child").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        containment: ".drag_drop_container"
    });

    $('.drop-parent').droppable({
        accept: ".drag-parent > .child",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            Dropped($(this), ui.draggable.click());
        }
    });
    $('.drag-parent').droppable({
        accept: function(draggable) {
            if($(this).attr('id').split('parent')[1] == draggable.attr('data-id')) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            Reverted($(this), ui.draggable.click());
        }
    });
    function Dropped($this, $item) {
        $item.css({'left': '0px', 'top': '0px'});
        $this.droppable("disable").css('opacity',0.9);;
        if($item.parent().hasClass('drop-parent')) {
            $item.parent().droppable("enable");
        } else {
            $('.text-input').val($item.attr('data-id'));
        }
        $this.append($item);
        $this.sortable();
    }
    function Reverted($this, $item) {
        $item.css({'left': '0px', 'top': '0px'});
        $item.parent().droppable("enable");
        $this.append($item);
        $('.droped_val').val('');
    }
```

```css
.drop-parent {
    //border: 1px solid red!important;
    /* background-color: red; */
    //width: 640px; /*can be in percentage also.*/
    height: 42px;
    width: 100px;
    //margin: 0 auto;
    left:-4px;
    //padding: 10px;
    top:184px;
    position: relative;
}
.dragbody {
    //border: 1px solid blue!important;
    /* background-color: red; */
    //width: 281px;
    //position: relative;
    //height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://emea.focusvision.com/survey/selfserve/2140/190505/drag1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://emea.focusvision.com/survey/selfserve/2140/190505/drag2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="drag_drop_container">
    <div class="cards">
        <table align="center" class="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="drag-parent" id="parent1">
                        <div class="child" data-id=1><img src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/happy.png"/></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="drag-parent" id="parent2">
                        <div class="child" data-id=2><img src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/neutral.png"/></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="drag-parent" id="parent3">
                        <div class="child" data-id=3><img src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/sad.png"/></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="dragbody">
        <div align="center" class="drop-parent">
        </div>
        <img src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/body.png" width="250px"/>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer updated JS link: https://output.jsbin.com/zafoqodaxa

Comment: First off you run $this.droppable("disable") when you drop an item on it in the function Dropped() if you remove that you can drop them all on it but it wont replace the one already there

Comment: Ok thanks! but my requirement is that the 3 draggable divs parent1, parent2 and parent3 should interchange with each other on drop and storing their data-id into the text input. I have shared the code snippet as well.

Comment: @NicoShultz I have tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the `Dropped()` function so that it moves all old elements that where on the body back to their parent and then adds the new one.

```js
$(".child").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  containment: ".drag_drop_container"
});

$('.drop-parent').droppable({
  accept: ".drag-parent > .child",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    Dropped($(this), ui.draggable.click());
  }
});
$('.drag-parent').droppable({
  accept: function(draggable) {
    if ($(this).attr('id').split('parent')[1] == draggable.attr('data-id')) {
      return true;
    }
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    Reverted($(this), ui.draggable.click());
  }
});

function Dropped($this, $item) {
  $item.css({
    'left': '0px',
    'top': '0px'
  });
  if ($item.parent().hasClass('drop-parent')) {
    $item.parent().droppable("enable");
  } else {
    $('.text-input').val($item.attr('data-id'));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < $this.children().length; i++) {
        $oldElement = $($this.children()[i]);
    $("#parent" + $oldElement.data("id")).append($oldElement);
  }
  $this.append($item);
  $this.sortable();
}

function Reverted($this, $item) {
  $item.css({
    'left': '0px',
    'top': '0px'
  });
  $item.parent().droppable("enable");
  $this.append($item);
  $('.droped_val').val('');
}
```

```css
.drop-parent {
    //border: 1px solid red!important;
    /* background-color: red; */
    //width: 640px; /*can be in percentage also.*/
    height: 42px;
    width: 100px;
    //margin: 0 auto;
    left:-4px;
    //padding: 10px;
    top:184px;
    position: relative;
}
.dragbody {
    //border: 1px solid blue!important;
    /* background-color: red; */
    //width: 281px;
    //position: relative;
    //height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://emea.focusvision.com/survey/selfserve/2140/190505/drag1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://emea.focusvision.com/survey/selfserve/2140/190505/drag2.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="drag_drop_container">
      <div class="cards">
        <table align="center" class="Table1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="drag-parent" id="parent1">
                <div class="child" data-id=1>
                  <img data-parent-id="1" src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/happy.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="drag-parent" id="parent2">
                <div class="child" data-id=2>
                  <img data-parent-id="2" src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/neutral.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="drag-parent" id="parent3">
                <div class="child" data-id=3>
                  <img data-parent-id="3" src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/sad.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="dragbody">
        <div align="center" class="drop-parent">
        </div>
        <img src="https://singapore.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/54e/200701/body.png" width="250px" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```